# ASP.NET Core 6 - ignore not present fields in JSON Runtime deserialisation

Tags: json, asp.net-core, deserialization

I have method on my controller that accept JSON from body. I have model of JSON class that include all possible fields. But not all fields can be in the incoming JSON.

For example:

```
public partial class File
{
    [JsonProperty("ID", Required = Required.Always)]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CategoryCaption", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string CategoryCaption { get; set; }
}
```

incoming json:

```
"File": {
        "ID": "12321",
        "Name": "test.txt"
        }
```

or:

```
"File": {
        "ID": "12321",
        "Name": "test.txt",
        "CategoryCaption": "incoming"
        }
```

Need to accept both
but i got error: "The CategoryCaption field is required."

I've been trying to add

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(option =>
        {
            option.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition =
                JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        });
```

But I still get an error in runtime

Comment: Change it to `public string? CategoryCaption { get; set; }` so it's a nullable `string`.